# How can we create a typeface from a downloadable font?

Tags: android, android-fonts

I have a helper method that does the following:

```
public CustomTypefaceSpan(Context context, String typefaceName) {
    mTypeface = sTypefaceCache.get(typefaceName);

    if (mTypeface == null) {
        mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
                String.format("fonts/%s", typefaceName));

        // Cache the loaded Typeface
        sTypefaceCache.put(typefaceName, mTypeface);
    }
}
```

After switching to downloadable fonts we get the following exception because there isn't a font available in the assets folder. How could we perform this action with a downloadable font? Thank you!

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
                                                                      at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:206)
                                                                      at com.woot.util.ui.CustomTypefaceSpan.(CustomTypefaceSpan.java:19)
                                                                      at com.woot.util.ui.ActivityUtil.setTitleCustomFont(ActivityUtil.java:20)
                                                                      at com.woot.storelocator.selectstorelanding.SelectStoreActivity.onCreate(SelectStoreActivity.java:40)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: have you added the font to asset folder ?

Comment: I want to use downloadable fonts and not ship the font with the APK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sample code illustrates the overall Downloadable Fonts process:

```
 FontRequest request = new FontRequest("com.example.fontprovider.authority",
            "com.example.fontprovider", "my font", certs); 
    FontsContract.FontRequestCallback callback =
        new FontsContract.FontRequestCallback() { 
            @Override 
            public void onTypefaceRetrieved(Typeface typeface) {
                // Your code to use the font goes here 
                ... 
            } 

            @Override 
            public void onTypefaceRequestFailed(int reason) {
                // Your code to deal with the failure goes here 
                ... 
            } 
    }; 
FontsContract.requestFonts(context, request, callback , handler);
```

Comment: I am new to this. Can I use this in conjunction with the snippet above?

Comment: No because the above tries to retrieve the font from your assets folder and doesn't find it. If you think I answered your question feel free to up vote.